# To have somebody do something

Tags: english-to-german

In a reading lesson, the teacher may lead students to
see beyond the literal meaning of words in a text, using
a variety of clues **to have students understand what the
writer states** implicitly.

In this context, I'm having difficulties translating bold typed part in German, could this: "jemanden etwas tun lassen" make any sense if I had used, my attempt was like:

> [...]mit einer Vielzahl von Hinweisen lässt er sich Schüler verstehen,was ein Autor implizit betont.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your general idea is right but you made a mistake.

> [..] lässt er sich Schüler verstehen [..]

is not understandable. The word `sich` symbolizes that the teacher does this for him- or herself.

For this fragment, you don't need any reflexive component, so

> [..] lässt er die Schüler verstehen [..]

would be the correct translation.

You also made another mistake by translating the English definite article `the` with the indefinite German article `ein`.

So

> [..] was ein Autor implizit betont.

should be

> [..] was der Autor implizit betont.

Comment: Isn't "implizit betont" a contradiction? Either it is emphasized or implied...

Comment: @Iris you're right,I haven't thought about that xD

Comment: @Iris do you mean my translation was wrong, would I had used maybe "erklären" ?

Comment: @Bergmann your translation means something along the line ``implicitly emphasize`` which is antonymous because if something is emphasized, it is not implicit...

Comment: @Armin do I need to pick up "etwas implizit erklären" that's why?

Comment: @Bergmann I'd translate`` to state `` with ``nennen``, ``darlegen`` or ``bekunden``.

Comment: I agree with Armin. You could also just use the verb "implizieren".  "was der Autor impliziert"